# How can I parse a JSON object from an ENV variable and set a new environment variable in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to setup [Ory Kratos](https://www.ory.sh/docs/kratos/guides/docker) on ECS.

Their documentation says that you can run migrations with the following command...

```
docker -e DSN="engine://username:password@host:port/dbname" run oryd/kratos:v0.10 migrate sql -e
```

I'm trying to recreate this for an ECS task and the `Dockerfile` so far looks like this...

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM oryd/kratos:v0.10

COPY kratos /kratos

CMD ["-c", "/kratos/kratos.yml", "migrate", "sql", "-e", "--yes"]
```

It uses the base `oryd/kratos:v0.10` image, copies across a directory with some config and runs the migration command.

What I'm missing is a way to construct the `-e DSN="engine://username:password@host:port/dbname"`. I'm able to supply my database secret from AWS Secrets Manager directly to the ECS task, however the secret is a JSON object in a string containing the `engine`, `username`, `password`, `host`, `port` and `dbname` properties.

How can I securely construct the required `DSN` environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html) on injecting SecretsManager secrets. You can inject specific values from a JSON secret as individual environment variables. Search for `"Example referencing a specific key within a secret"` in the page I linked above. So the easiest way to accomplish this without adding a [JSON parser tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to your docker image, and writing a shell script to parse the JSON inside the container, is to simply have ECS inject each specific value as a separate environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely takes me a step closer.  


How would I construct the DSN string?  

I can see that the [migrate command](https://www.ory.sh/docs/kratos/cli/kratos-migrate-sql) can be called in the format `kratos migrate sql <database-url> [flags]` so I tried this...  

`CMD ["-c", "/kratos/kratos.yml", "migrate", "sql", "$RDS_CLUSTER_ENGINE://$RDS_CLUSTER_USERNAME:$RDS_CLUSTER_PASSWORD@$RDS_CLUSTER_HOST:$RDS_CLUSTER_PORT/$RDS_CLUSTER_DBNAME",  "--yes"]`. 

But that doesn't work because the variables aren't substituted.

Comment: I think you may need to add a small startup script to your docker image when you are building it, change your `CMD` to just run that script, basically change it to `CMD ["./start.sh"]` and then do the environment variable stuff inside that script.